How to split HTML code in a Freshdesk app
How to split HTML code in a Freshdesk app. I have a created a HTML app in Freshdesk. Below is the HTML code. Is there a way I can create another HTML component and import here in index.html.
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>A Template App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script async src="{{{appclient}}}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <p>Utilize this template code to build your App</p>
      <p id="apptext"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script defer src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script async type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@freshworks/crayons@v4/dist/crayons/crayons.esm.js"></script>
  <script async nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@freshworks/crayons@v4/dist/crayons/crayons.js"></script>
</html>

I couldn't find any option to split HTML files in Freshdesk app. I'm looking for functionality similar to what we have in Angular and React. Is there any such feature in Freshdesk.
